# Vuex: Store module cyclic dependency

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have the following situation:

**store/index.js**

```
import moduleA from '@/store/module-a';
import moduleB from '@/store/module-b';

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    A: moduleA,
    B: moduleB
  }
});
```

**store/module-a.js**

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    val: // constructed using localStorage
  }
};
```

**store/module-b.js**

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    val: // requires store/module-a.js state.val to construct
  },
  mutations: {
    add: function () {
      // requires store/module-a.js state.val
    }
  }
};
```

If I try to `import store from '@/store` inside of module B, and then access `store.state.A.val`, I'd get a cyclic dependency, where `store --> moduleB --> store`.

I can construct the `store.state.A.val` inside of module B, but that would be duplicating logic, and since module A is being loaded first, it would be nice if I could just access it from module A. Is that possible?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good use of modules, the primary use of which is **separation**

Comment: @Phil Module A is Settings, which is used by module B and module C (not included in this question), and any future modules. I'm not really sure what else I can do. Even if I put the settings in the "root" of the store rather than in it's own module, it seems that I'd still have the same problem. Modules B and C (and future modules) definitely do need to be separated.

Comment: If you need the same state in different store you should lift it up

Answer (score 0):

I'd construct your b store's val as a default, not including any info from settings. Then have a mutation or action that sets it up properly from settings (a). Probably should be an Action, since Mutations only get the local state, whereas Actions get a context that includes the `rootState` from which you can access the other modules.
Alternatively you can just use a getter for `b.val`; getters have access to `rootState` (and `rootGetters`) as well.